# Unit Testing with Mockito & Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, mockito, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to implement testing for an android app that I'm building. One of the tests involves an interactor file I wrote (`DatabaseInteractor.java`) that connects to Google Firestore. The default constructor sets the `FirestoreFirebase` object to `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();`.

I am using Mockito & JUnit for my unit tests. When I attempt to create a DataBaseInteractor object in my Unit Test, I get the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

Apparently this error occurs when the default constructor is called in my Unit Test. I'm not sure why this is happening. I am able to create a DataBaseInteractor object in other parts of my android app without issue. Are there perhaps limitations to when and where I can initialize a class that utilizes `FireBaseFireStore` objects? If I want to mock the behavior of FireBase for unit testing, how do I get around these restrictions?

EDIT: A truncated version of my `DataBaseInteractor.java` file:

```
public class DatabaseInteractor {
    private static User theUser;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private DocumentReference userData;


    public DatabaseInteractor() {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        theUser = new User();
    }
 // ... various methods that add/retrieve Users from FireStore ... //
}
```

Comment: post your DatabaseInteractor.java file, you probably need to mock the Firestore instance

Comment: Posted my DataBaseInteractor file!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to inject the FirebaseFirestore instance in your constructor so that it can be mocked, something like:

```
public class DatabaseInteractor {
    private static User theUser;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private DocumentReference userData;


    public DatabaseInteractor(FirebaseFirestore firestore) {
        db = firestore
        theUser = new User();
    }
 // ... various methods that add/retrieve Users from FireStore ... //
}
```

The in your test you can mock `FirebaseFirestore` with Mockito:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
  FirebaseFirestore mockFirestore = Mockito.mock(FirebaseFirestore.class)
  Mockito.when(mockFirestore.someMethodCallYouWantToMock()).thenReturn(something)

  DatabaseInteractor interactor = new DatabaseInteractor(mockFirestore)

  // some assertion or verification
}
```

I'd suggest you read about dependency injection, it will make unit testing a lot easier if you can pass in mocks of your dependencies in the constructor instead of instantiating them inside it.

Comment: Jorge, thank you for this. Do you happen to know if you have to pass any dependency you are mocking in a class via the constructor, or this just a quirk of mocking Firebase objects?

Comment: You don't have to, you could pass a mock via a method for example. But you probably should. Generally speaking, unit tests are meant to test a piece of code by itself without external dependencies. In your case, you want to test that the functionality of your interactor works, regardless of how the firestore, or any other dependency behaves.
You can accomplish this by mocking all of the dependencies and the easy (and clean) way to do that is with constructor injection.