# How to run unit tests on Android Firebase Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So I am building a chat App using Firebase Backend. Before implementing ViewModel and the actual fragment, I want to check whether my Firebase Repository works or not. My call to get the users will go like this

Fragmet -> ViewModel -> Repository -> FirebaseRepository -> suspend fun getAllUsers() : ArrayList

The code is :

```
class Repository(val firebaseRepository : FirebaseRepository) {

    suspend fun getAllUsersFromFirebase() : ArrayList<UserInfo> {
        return firebaseRepository.getAllUsers()
    }

}
```

```
class FirebaseRepository() {

    private val TAG = "FIREBASE REPOSITORY : "

    private val firebaseAuth:FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val firebaseDatabase :FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

    suspend fun getAllUsers() : ArrayList<UserInfo> {
        val ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference("/users")
        val userList = ArrayList<UserInfo>()

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"$snapshot")
                    val tempList = ArrayList<UserInfo>()
                    for(child in snapshot.children){
                        val temp = child.getValue(UserInfo::class.java)
                        if(!temp?.userId!!.equals(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid)) {
                            tempList.add(temp)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG,"$error ${error.message}")
            }

        })

        if(userList.isEmpty()) {
            userList.add(UserInfo("NO USER FOUND","NO USER FOUND","NO USER FOUND","NO USER FOUND"))
        }

        return userList
    }
}
```

So how do I test this? I surmise that firebaseAuth may pose a problem. I think I can deal with it but how do I test this firebase call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check whether my firebase Repository works or not.

It won't work because you are returning the `userList` as a result of a method, which is actually not possible since the Firebase API is asynchronous. So the issue here is that the listener you have attached is being invoked some unknown amount of time after the query finishes and you'll never know how long it's going to take. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

That being said, your `userList` will be empty until the callback is invoked. This means that you should always use the results from within the callback. I have written an article regarding this topic called that will help you understand the concept:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)

If you want to create a unit test, then I recommend you use [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) and use the answer the answer from the following post:

- [Unit Testing with Mockito & Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473006/unit-testing-with-mockito-firebase)

P.S. Your `getAllUsers()` method doesn't need to be a suspend fun, because you aren't using any await() there. If you want to use that, I recommend you read the following article:

- [How to optimize Firebase Realtime Database calls to improve performance?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-optimize-firebase-realtime-database-calls-to-improve-performance-cc63dad374d5)

Comment: Okay. So my suspend function will return an empty List because it is async and by the time it gets the data my function would've already returned a list. I knew that,just missed it. To solve this I think I will use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { firebaseCall } . For the testing part,I will look into the links provided by you. Thanks @Alex.

Comment: Try to read the linked [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5), and check the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase).

Comment: Thanks @Alex . I read the whole .get() Link and I found a bit different approach to what you have used. So I completed the function as : userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener{ // makes the list }.await() .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this is:

```
    // Optional -- Robolectric environment
    const val coreTest = "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    const val mockito = "org.mockito:mockito-core:5.5.0"
    // Optional -- mockito-kotlin
    const val mockitoKotlin = "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:5.1.0"
    // Optional -- Mockk framework
    const val mockk = "io.mockk:mockk:v1.13.8"
```

add the above libraries.

Code: FileTest.kt

```
@Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(FileTest::class)
    }

    @Test
    fun getAllUsersFromFirebase() = runBlocking {
        val getRepositoryUseCase = mock(Repository::class.java)

        `when`(getRepositoryUseCase.invoke()).thenReturn(listData())
        val response = getRepositoryUseCase.invoke()

        Assert.assertTrue(response == listUserDummy())
    }
```